# HP Server not booting - "PXE-E53: No boot filename received"?

Tags: boot, pxe, hp-proliant

We have an issue with our HP DL360 G5 server not booting.

It starts up, but gets stuck at a "PXE-E53: No boot filename received" error.

Can you shed some light on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to boot over network. Is this intended?

Comment: It's hitting "Network" in the boot order. If Network is in the boot order after a drive you expected to boot from, that tells me the drive (or at least the bootable file-system on the drive) is faulty, so it's skipping the device. As-is there's not enough info to give you an accurate answer, please add details about what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2):

This is shown when you try to boot via [**PXE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment). When booting in such mode, the server will try to find a `TFTP` server which will retrieve a list of different preconfigured images of operating systems available to install. You usually use this boot mode *only* when you want to install the operating system on the server, it is not needed afterwards.

This can be configured in the BIOS. At boot time, enter the BIOS (<kbd>F2</kbd>) to check the boot order, and precede the hard disk to the PXE mode if you want to avoid your server look for TFTP servers each time it boots.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your views. We had an issue of one of the hard disk drives popped out a little bit. So it was not able to detect the bootable drive. After we fixed the hard drive correctly then it came back with below options:

Select "F1" to continue with logical drive(s) disabled

Select "F2" to accept data loss and to re-enable logical drive(s)
RESUME = "F1" OR "F2" KEY

Pressed F2 to continue and everything came up as usual.

Thanks and Appreciate your comments.